# Configuring one way external incoming request

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

I am configuring a trust between 2 domains. Both are having windows server 2003 r2. let the 1st server have the domain abc.xyz.com and domain of second server is def.ghi.com. I have configured DNS and now it can ping the server 1 from server 2.

While configuring the new trust wizard I am getting an error as shown below:

```
"The secure channel reset will be attempted. The secure channel reset failed with error 1787. The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship."
```

I was configuring one way external incoming request.. Can someone please show me the right path asap since my work is on hold now..

FYI, These 2 servers are VM's and in VMWare environment and both in different forests.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out my own solution.. Need to create an  external incoming trust on the other domain.. And select "Accept all incoming connections".